# Rename and synonym [passbook] tag to [wallet]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

iOS has a feature to store credit cards, loyalty passes and things like a digital wallet or passbook.

Wallet seems to be the English name replacing passbook entirely a few years ago (around 3).

On the site, in December 2018 wallet is a synonym of passbook.

The same applies to iBooks, it was renamed to Books and needs to be changed.

Should we swap the synonym so that the words wallet are the tag used?

Comment: Did my edit to change one of the directions make sense to you? Wallet replaces passbook and not was replaced by in my eyes - so I changed that sentence.

Comment: @bmike I get your edit, it still means the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With +3 votes, we have merged all questions into [wallet](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wallet) and established passbook as a synonym. Thanks @Daniil for the recommendation and the people that voted to approve this.

This is a low volume tag (less than 50 questions and zero people have favorited it)

```
updating count for master tag, new count: 34
tag remapping of [wallet] and [passbook] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd support reversing this merge. Any objections or cleanup needed if we implement this?

Comment: Could we consider the same for iBooks. In the latest update it was renamed to boools

Comment: I'm not seeing any issue with it.... If there is any cleanup it will be minimal.  There's only [34 questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passbook) tagged 'passbook'

Comment: Can the merge be implemented now?

Comment: @DaniilManokhin i would prefer this answer gets +5 to +10 but the majority of the moderators have approved so I will proceed. Let’s work on getting votes up on the answer to indicate broad support for tag cleanup going forward.